# How to get every single character form inspect element on a dynamic website?

Tags: javascript, python, html

Please read the problem and requirement carefully as I have searched and tried innumerable things before adding a new question.

This is the code to get all elements from inspect element. Even though the code is in Python, Javascript code to do it will also work as I am executing it in Python.

```
from selenium import webdriver

url="https://www.websiteWithLotsOfJavascript.com"

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'my_path')
driver.get(url)

#This will get the initial html - before javascript
html1 = driver.page_source

# This will get the html after on-load javascript
html2 = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML;")

#copied.txt has the manually copied inspect element
f=open("copied.txt",encoding="utf8")
copiedString=f.read();

print(len(copiedString))
print(len(html1))
print(len(html2))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
3914543
588849
588740
```

The lengths of html1 and html2 are almost same but length of the copiedString *(which is manually copied by me by going into inspect element and then right clicking the outermost HTML tag and then clicking `Edit As HTML` and then selecting all text and copy)* is almost 6 times the length of html1 and html2.

[image]

I have tried both `document.documentElement.outerHTML` and `document.documentElement.innerHTML`.
I also tried pausing the program with time.sleep() before script execution line (thinking maybe network delay may cause everything to not load) but same result. I guess I have read various articles and almost every stackoverflow question on getting inspect element but nothing seems to work.

What can be causing the difference **OR** is there a way to get the complete HTML by some other means?

Comment: What's the URL?

Comment: Any youtube playlist URL - For example:  "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4o29bINVT4EG_y-k5jGoOu3-Am8Nvi10"

Comment: Sounds like YouTube is not providing the same content to PhantomJS as it would to a regular browser. Since PhantomJS is headless, this isn't surprising.

Comment: I feel, there must be a way to do it without opening a browser window, maybe even by a workaround. Just a reminder that if you feel the question is useful and clear, maybe up voting it would increase its chances of reaching someone with an answer.